# What is accurate rendering of the expression "invalid at computed-value time"?

Tags: перевод, информатика

I tried to render the expression "invalid at computed-value time" into very understandable Russian as "недопустимое значение", and so trimmed in a way that retains no real essentials. I really don't want to say "invalid value".

Let me explain... this is a computing term. For example, I have a function, an input value and a conditional statement that defines if an output value returned by the function is acceptable. I don't know if the input value is valid to be taken as an input because it depends on what the output value is. Later, at computation time, the output — the computed value — proves to be unacceptable, so the input value is invalid at computed-value time.

What would be the accurate rendering of the expression, so that it never needs to be explained in order to be properly understood?

Comment: Your request is very specific; you cannot say that in a concise and easily understandable fashion at the same time. However, your original English clause doesn't seem easy either. I'd say something like *значение, невалидное/неприемлемое по итогу вычисления* [*функции*] or *значение, приводящее к некорректному/невалидному/неприемлемому вычислению* [*функции*].

Comment: Значения аргумента, исключаемые по результатам вычислений?

Comment: The expression "invalid at computed-value time" is counter-intuitive to me. "Invalid at some **time**" usually implies that at some other moment of time the same value can be valid. But in the explanation I don't see any evidence that, for example, the output of your function depends on current time, or anything like that.

Comment: If it is an error message from the condition statement after the function, I'd simply describe the situation from your explanation:`Function [func_name] called with arguments [func_args] returned invalid value.` -- `Функция [func_name] c аргументами [func_args] вернула недопустимое значение`. Or choose any variant from answers here.

Comment: "invalid at computed-value time" == `недостоверно до конца вычислений`.

Comment: Your are trying to translate an obscure error message with garbled semantics. It is obscure because it describes the failure in terms of the internal workings of the program rather than the task at hand. Garbled and unhelpful error message can not be made easily understandable by a translator. Replace it with something which reflects the meaning of the "computed value" such as "Safe operating limits exceeded. Reduce speed or load."

Answer (score 7):

I would approach it similarly to a stable expression:

> **"Invalid run-time value"** which translates to **"Недопустимое значение во время выполнения."**

If we need to differentiate **compute-time** from **run-time**, we can translate:

> **"Invalid at computed-value time"** as **"Недопустимое значение во время вычисления."**

In my opinion, the literal translation is "Недопустимо во время вычисления значения." But that phrase (adverbial clause) is less convenient for usage in different contexts.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose a translation based on your description. You said that a certain value being used as an input parameter leads to an unacceptable result. So, in Russian it would be something like this:

> Значение переменной [which you use as input] приводит к неприемлемому результату

P. S. As a programmer, I prefer clear error explanations. Error text has to explain a situation as much as possible, so it's more of an explanation than a translation.

Answer (score 2):

Folant,

If I understood your task correctly, you're dealing with a function and a conditional statement that evaluates these function outputs. In this case, your function + the conditional statement is basically another function that has its own range and domain. For this reason, if an output value isn't acceptable, I'd simply say: "The input parameter is out of the range" and, by definition, that automatically means that the corresponding output value isn't acceptable in a process of computation. A Russian equivalent for "The input parameter is out of the range" is "Входной параметер вне области определения", and this message sounds scientific and elegant in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

"Недопустимое значение" seems to be totally fine for what you described. I don't see any problem. If you want to explain the reason for this value being invalid, you can explain it briefly, like "Недопустимое значение: *(the condition that makes it invalid goes here)*".

Unfortunately, I don't see any real way of going with no explanation at all in your case, unless you explain it somewhere else, which, in turn, isn't going without an explanation. :)

Comment: But there is no mistake at all in the output value, so I can't say "invalid value". Rather the value is not acceptable to step ahead in computation. Is "Недопустимый во время вычисления значения" more complicated rendering to understand?

Comment: Недопустимое значение аргумента.

Comment: @Folant "Недопустимое значение" doesn't imply that there is any mistake.  "Ошибочное значение" would do, however. If you want to clarify that you can't continue with that value, say exactly that: "Невозможно продолжить: недопустимое значение аргумента" (Impossible to continue: invalid argument).

Answer (score 1):

Если по завершении вычислений выясняется, что входное значение недопустимо… Входное значение, чья недопустимость выясняется по завершении вычислений… — В таких случаях бывает полезно переводить описательно.

То есть значение, которое всегда было недопустимым (в математическом смысле: функция на этом значении не определена), но о котором можно это выяснить только по окончании вычислений — по проверочному условию, наложенному на вычисленное выходное значение.

I get the impression that you came up with terminology that was difficult to understand even in English.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, the problem of finding the input value from the output is called "the inverse problem". So what you're describing is a check of whether a certain input value produces an output value residing in a certain subset of the codomain of your function.

In Russian, you can express your point like this:

значение аргумента, приводящее к результату, лежащему за пределами желаемой области значений, - и в этом смысле неприемлемое

Answer (score 0):

> Входное значение недопустимо

You don't have to render a complete sentence, as many answers suggest. Just focus on the primary relationship between things.

The difference is that the English message doesn't talk about input, which is, in my opinion, confusing, while focusing on the obscure compute-time term, which is redundant — *of course* you need to evaluate in order to figure out whether input is correct is not. But in a case where you also need to signal statically invalid input:

> Входное значение вне диапазона

Note that having a proper verb isn't necessary in Russian.